# Create a CustomControl in C# WinUI 3 containing other CustomControls

Tags: c#, xaml, wrapper, dependency-properties, winui-3

I'm new both to WinUI and XAML and I'm creating a **WinUI 3 Library** that contains various `CustomControl`.

They're all independent and can be used stand alone. But one of those controls, is made by embedding some other custom controls that are in the library.

##### XAML of Container control

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyCustomControls">
    
    <Style TargetType="local:CustomContainer">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomContainer">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <local:CustomTextBlock x:Name="Text"
                                            DisplayMode="{TemplateBinding DisplayMode}"
                                            Message="{TemplateBinding Message}">
                        </local:CustomTextBlock>

                        <local:CustomIndicator x:Name="Indicator"></local:CustomIndicator>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

As you can see in the sample, the `CustomTextBlock` custom control contains 2 `DependecyProperty` (`DisplayMode` and `Message`) that I need to "replicate" on the `CustomContainer` control to be able to set them when I want to use the `CustomContainer` on a page.

Here in the XAML I've used `TemplateBinding` with 2 `DependecyProperty` that I should declare on the code behind of `CustomContainer`.

##### Code behind of `CustomTextBlock` control

```cs
private static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayModeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(DisplayMode), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public bool DisplayMode
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(DisplayModeProperty);
    set => SetValue(DisplayModeProperty, value);
}

private static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(Message), typeof(string), typeof(CustomTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), (d, e) => ((CustomTextBlock)d).MessageChanged(d, e)));

public string Message
{
    get => (string)GetValue(MessageProperty);
    set => SetValue(MessageProperty, value);
}
```

How can I expose the 2 properties of `CustomTextBlock` on the `CustomContainer` control so that those values directly sets the underlying properties? Do they still need to be `DependencyProperty` type?

It seems something like wrapping or inheritance concept, but I'm not able to figure it out, especially for the `Message` property that is also registered with an event handler.

Comment: Usually you need to relay them. So create the same DPs in the outer control. If the number of DPs that you want to expose are too much, you might need to consider inheritance.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding Can you please explain in more details both the proposed solution, maybe also with some code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sample, we have:

- `InnerControl` with a `TextBlock` and an `InnerText` dependency-property bound to the `TextBlock`
- `OuterControl` with an `InnerControl` and a `TextForInnerControl` dependency-property bound to the `InnerControl`
- `MainWindow` with a `TextBox` and an `OuterControl` where its `TextForInnerControl` is bound to the `TextBox`

The text coming form the `TextBox` in the `MainWindow` will be passed to the `OuterControl` and then to the `InnerControl`.

Here's the code:

**InnerControl.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace WinUI3CustomControlTest;

public sealed class InnerControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(InnerText),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(InnerControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public InnerControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(InnerControl);
    }

    public string InnerText
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(InnerTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(InnerTextProperty, value);
    }
}
```

**OuterControl.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace WinUI3CustomControlTest;

public sealed class OuterControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextForInnerControlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(TextForInnerControl),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(OuterControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public OuterControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(OuterControl);
    }

    public string TextForInnerControl
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextForInnerControlProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextForInnerControlProperty, value);
    }
}
```

**Generic.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3CustomControlTest">

    <Style TargetType="local:OuterControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:OuterControl">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <local:InnerControl InnerText="{TemplateBinding TextForInnerControl}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="local:InnerControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:InnerControl">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding InnerText}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WinUI3CustomControlTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3CustomControlTest"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox
            x:Name="InputTextBox"
            PlaceholderText="Enter you text.." />
        <Button
            Click="Button_Click"
            Content="Set text programmatically" />
        <local:OuterControl
            x:Name="MyOuterControl"
            TextForInnerControl="{x:Bind InputTextBox.Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System;

namespace WinUI3CustomControlTest;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyOuterControl.TextForInnerControl = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, it works! But what if I want to set the `TextForInnerControl` value from code using a method like `SetText("string", otherOption)`? Should I create a public method on `InnerControl`? Or on `OuterControl`? Or both...?

Comment: To access a control from code-behind, you need to name it with ``x:Name``. I added a ``Button`` which sets text to ``TextForInnerControl`` property.

Comment: And what if I want to access an inner control of a `CustomControl` from code behind? I tried with the `{x:Name}` but it seems it's not the right way, because the name it's not recognized and so I don't have a reference to the control.

Comment: If you need to access a control (``InnerControl`` in this case) hidden inside a control (``OuterControl``) in this case, I just happen to post a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/ai-koyvgbWY) last week. It might help you.

Comment: Ok, watched it. So, the only way to get access to the controls of a container control (of type `CustomControl`) is through `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild()` method used in a custom implementation like you did? There's no other way like the "automagic" in `WindowsForms` or `ASP.NET`? Or even like it is in a XAML `Window` object, where you can reference the contained controls just by using `this.xxx`??

Comment: I came with another approach that might help you. I created another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663277/how-to-access-your-nested-custom-control/73663278#73663278) and answered it myself.